# Instalando Visual Studio 2015 - Erro durante instalação

Tags: visual-studio, instalador

O meu problema é o seguinte: Eu já tentei instalar o VS 2015 Community e Enterprise mas os dois apresentarão o mesmo problema (tela abaixo) sempre que instalo com a minha internet via WiFi ou cabo (Live TIM 35Mb Modem Sagemcom F@ST4310), a instalação nem completa mesmo dando Retry. Já usando a internet da empresa esse problema não aparece. Alguém sabe o que poderia ser?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não funciona, ele volta para essa página..

Comment: Esta pergunta tem dois votos de fechamento como fora do escopo por não ser sobre programação e dois votos de fechamento como não estando clara o suficiente. Dada a descrição (*usando a internet da empresa esse problema não aparece*), realmente não parece ser uma pergunta no escopo do site. De qualquer forma, a resposta mais provável é que algum erro de rede causado pela má qualidade da sua conexão interrompa o download na metade e o instalador não saiba prosseguir de onde parou, restando-lhe apenas tentar a instalação offline. Bem, sinto muito, mais darei o último voto de fechamento.

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser uma falha para baixar o pacote (voce teria que olhar o log de erro da instalação)

Mas uma alternativa é baixar a ISO do VS2015

Para a versão Community 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146

e para a versão Enterprise 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48143

Nos dois, voce clica no botão Download e escolhe baixar o ISO. Assim voce efetua a instalação toda offline.

Comment: tentei isso.. funciona.. mas eu não entendo o por que só acontece quando conecto no modem da minha casa...

Comment: como comentei teria que avaliar o log,

Comment: queria saber se tem que liberar alguma porta ou algo assim...

Comment: onde posso ver o log?

Comment: verifica na pasta appdata do seu usuário C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: por esta pasta vai ser difícil, tem muitos arquivos, mas a Microsoft tem uma ferramenta para coletar estes dados. voce pode achar no final deste link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx